# Exodus Rabbah 1:5 These are the names of the Children of Israel

Tags: names, midrash, commentaries, yetziat-mitzrayim, parashas-shemos

Parashat Shemot starts with a list of the names of all who came to Egypt, the Midrash Rabba 1:5 rereads all these names, with a new set of meanings reflecting the upcoming exodus.

Searching for the way it rereads the names i found this:
Exodus Rabbah 1:5: These are the names of the Children of Israel– for the sake of the redemption are they mentioned here. Reuben, as it says-I have surely seen the affliction of my people in Egypt. Shimon, as it says- And God heard their cries, etc (quoting Exodus 3:7).

Could someone please give me the full translation with the other names?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to keep to the literal interpretation as much as possible.

‘Reuven’, as it is stated, (Exodus 3, 7,) “I have surely seen the affliction of My people.”

‘Shimon’, named for (Exodus 2, 24,) “And God heard their groaning.”

‘Levi’, named so because the Holy One, blessed be He connected to their plight from the midst of the bush, to fulfil what is stated, (Psalms 91, 15) “I am with him in trouble.”

‘Yehudah’, named so because they thanked the Holy One, blessed be He.

‘Yissachar’, because the Holy One, blessed be He rewarded their slavery with the spoils of Egypt and the spoils of the sea, to fulfil what was stated, (Genesis 15, 14,) “And afterward shall they come out with great wealth.”

‘Zevulun’, named so because the Holy One, blessed be He brought His Presence among them, as it is stated, (Exodus 25, 8,) “And they shall make Me a sanctuary and I will dwell in them.” And Zevulun is but (a reference to) the holy temple as it is stated, (Kings 1, 8, 13,) “I have surely built You a house of habitation, a place for You to dwell in forever.”

‘Binyamin’, named for (Exodus 15, 6,) “Thy right hand, G-d, glorious in power.”

‘Dan’, named for (Genesis 15, 14,) “And also, the nation that will enslave them I shall judge afterward shall they come out with great wealth.”

‘Naftali’, named for (the) Torah and commandments that the Holy One, blessed be He gave them that are described as (Psalms 9, 11,) “And sweeter than honey and the honeycomb.”

‘Gad’ is named for the Manna that the Holy One, blessed be He fed them which was (Exodus 16, 31,) “Like the coriander seed.”

‘Asher’ named so because they gladdened all those who heard of their redemption and greatness, as it is written (Malachi 3, 12,) “And all the nations will call you happy, for you shall be a delightful land, says G-d, Lord of hosts.”

‘Yosef’, named so because in the future the Holy One, blessed be He will again (lit. add and) redeem Israel from the evil kingdom just as He redeemed them from Egypt, as it is written, (Isaiah 11, 11,) “And it shall be on that day, that G-d will set His hand again the second time etc.”